# Como substituir a uma declaração "import" dentro de um XML schema, pelo conteúdo do XSD a ser importado?

Tags: xml, xml-schema

Tenho o seguinte tag de XML Schema:

```
<xsd:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
    schemaLocation="xmldsig-core-schema20020212.xsd" />
```

E gostaria de saber com substituir esse *import* pelo seu valor no XSD que esta sendo importado.
Ou seja, em vez de ter dois schemas XSD, só criar um arquivo.
Simplesmente "jogar" o conteúdo dentro do outro não resolve pois já tentei, de forma a não declarar outra tag `<xsd:schema...>`.

Comment: O que você está tentando fazer com o XSD? Porque precisa fazer isso?

Comment: Desculpe brother. Nem lembro direito. Acredito que estava tentando validar o arquivo em alguma ferramenta online e estava dando erro devido a esse dependência. De qualquer forma não precisei mais. Obrigado.

Comment: Geralmente a validação de XML online eles pedem para enviar o XSD junto, portanto não é necessário adicionar no corpo do XML nada referente (ao menos as ferramentas online que testei).